# How to group data within a range of contigious timestamps

Tags: sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table made up of rows of data collected through an indeterministic polling process. Each row has a start and end timestamp denoting the time period in which the data was collected. In some cases the data was collected contiguously, in which case the timestamp of one row will have the  same value as the start timestamp for the next row. In other cases there is a break in time between one row and the next.

For example, in the table below, rows number 1,2,3 and 4 are all part of one time series of data. Similarly for rows 5, 6, 7 and 8 and again for rows 9 and 10. In between are time periods for which I do not have data.

```
Row  Start_Timestamp      End_Timestamp           Data_Item
---  ---------------      --------------          ---------
1    2019-08-12_22:07:53  2019-08-12_22:09:57     100      
2    2019-08-12_22:09:57  2019-08-12_22:12:01     203      
3    2019-08-12_22:12:01  2019-08-12_22:13:03     487      
4    2019-08-12_22:13:03  2019-08-12_22:16:19     113      
5    2019-08-12_22:24:34  2019-08-12_22:26:37     632      
6    2019-08-12_22:26:37  2019-08-12_22:27:40     532      
7    2019-08-12_22:27:40  2019-08-12_22:28:42     543      
8    2019-08-12_22:28:42  2019-08-12_22:31:57     142      
9    2019-08-13_19:56:06  2019-08-13_19:57:08     351      
10   2019-08-13_19:57:08  2019-08-13_19:58:10     982
```

I would like to groups these contiguous time series ideally as follows:

```
Row  Series  Start_Timestamp      End_Timestamp           Data_Item   
---  ------  ---------------      --------------          -----------  
1    1       2019-08-12_22:07:53  2019-08-12_22:09:57     100
2    1       2019-08-12_22:09:57  2019-08-12_22:12:01     203
3    1       2019-08-12_22:12:01  2019-08-12_22:13:03     487
4    1       2019-08-12_22:13:03  2019-08-12_22:16:19     113
5    2       2019-08-12_22:24:34  2019-08-12_22:26:37     632
6    2       2019-08-12_22:26:37  2019-08-12_22:27:40     532
7    2       2019-08-12_22:27:40  2019-08-12_22:28:42     543
8    2       2019-08-12_22:28:42  2019-08-12_22:31:57     142
9    3       2019-08-13_19:56:06  2019-08-13_19:57:08     351
10   3       2019-08-13_19:57:08  2019-08-13_19:58:10     982
```

I am new to SQL and have been struggling with this problem. I appreciate any insights or advice on how I might achieve this.

Comment: Hi @seanfir please can you tell us what database do you use, Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL or something else ? Thanks!  Also, you say: "For example, in the table below, rows number 1,2,3 and 4 are all part of one time series of data" - please can you explain little bit more, for example how do we recognize that the first 4 rows are a part of series 1 ? Thanks!

Comment: I am using Amazon's AWS Athena, which uses Presto with ANSI SQL. If you look closely at my table you will notice that the 1st time sequence (row 1) runs from 2019-08-12_22:07:53 to 2019-08-12_22:09:57 and the 2nd time sequence runs from 2019-08-12_22:09:57 to 2019-08-12_22:12:01. So the 2nd time sequence begins exactly as the 1st time sequence ends (the end timestamp for row 1 equals the start timestamp for row 2). This is also true for row 2 to 3 and row 3 to 4.  There is a break in time between row 4 and 5, i.e. the end_timestamp for row 4 does not equal the start_timestamp for row 5..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified gaps-and-island problem. Assuming that your RDBMS support window functions, you can approach this with a window sum. When the `Start_Timestamp` of record is different than the `End_Timestamp` of the previous record, a new group starts:

```
select
    t.Row,
    sum(case when Start_Timestamp = lag_End_Timestamp then 0 else 1 end) 
        over(order by End_Timestamp) series,
    t.Start_Timestamp,
    t.End_Timestamp,
    t.Data_Item
from (
    select
        t.*,
        lag(End_Timestamp) over (order by End_Timestamp) lag_End_Timestamp
    from mytable t
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10e255df7779b37bdd453143ca55fc40)**:

```
Row | series | Start_Timestamp     | End_Timestamp       | Data_Item
--: | -----: | :------------------ | :------------------ | --------:
  1 |      1 | 2019-08-12 22:07:53 | 2019-08-12 22:09:57 |       100
  2 |      1 | 2019-08-12 22:09:57 | 2019-08-12 22:12:01 |       203
  3 |      1 | 2019-08-12 22:12:01 | 2019-08-12 22:13:03 |       487
  4 |      1 | 2019-08-12 22:13:03 | 2019-08-12 22:16:19 |       113
  5 |      2 | 2019-08-12 22:24:34 | 2019-08-12 22:26:37 |       632
  6 |      2 | 2019-08-12 22:26:37 | 2019-08-12 22:27:40 |       532
  7 |      2 | 2019-08-12 22:27:40 | 2019-08-12 22:28:42 |       543
  8 |      2 | 2019-08-12 22:28:42 | 2019-08-12 22:31:57 |       142
  9 |      3 | 2019-08-13 19:56:06 | 2019-08-13 19:57:08 |       351
 10 |      3 | 2019-08-13 19:57:08 | 2019-08-13 19:58:10 |       982
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very clear and works very well for me.